# The input is not a valid Base-64 string Error, My JSON uses double quotation marks instead of single quotations

Tags: json, delphi, firemonkey, idhttp

I am trying to send a `JSON` post, but my `JSON` seems to differ a little bit from what the site usually sends
Here is what i am sending:

```
{"CodeNumberTextBox":"","txusername":"yC6IBEbznlRlKOKv8zrhiA","txpass":"pAQAyrr5u9/hK35iTIlt7Q=="}
```

Here is what the website sends when you click login:

```
{ CodeNumberTextBox:'', txusername:'yC6IBEbznlRlKOKv8zrhiA', txpass:'pAQAyrr5u9/hK35iTIlt7Q==' }
```

Here is the error i get when i send my JSON:
`'The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or an illegal character among the padding characters. '`
I use the code below to create my `JSON`:

```
  jsonRawRequest := TJSONObject.Create;
  jsonObject.AddPair('CodeNumberTextBox', '');
  jsonObject.AddPair('txusername', 'yC6IBEbznlRlKOKv8zrhiA');
  jsonObject.AddPair('txpass', 'pAQAyrr5u9/hK35iTIlt7Q==');
  jsonRequest := TStringStream.Create(jsonRawRequest.ToString(), TEncoding.UTF8);

  idHttp.Request.ContentType := 'application/json';
  idHttp.Request.Referer := 'SomeURL';
  idHttp.Post(URL, jsonRequest, ms)
```

Comment: The double quotes is considered the standard way to do it for any strings including identifier names.

Comment: And you are really sending the string 'something'? Or did you change that from the real value?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I only changed the real user and password with "something" for security reasons, everything else is the same.

Comment: You will have to decide if you want to support the website's non-standard JSON like format or try and get them to support and use JSON. Try both versions at https://jsonlint.com/   then look at the standard: http://www.json.org/

Comment: And where is the base64 encoding performed in your code?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Oh, the website does actually encode the username and password, which means the website post fills "txusername" and "txpass" with encoded values, since i have yet to discover how they are being coded, i am using the user and password in an encoded state, i will update my main post to show this.