# Problem with login using idhttp, the website doesn't send any username and password with its posts

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, indy, idhttp

*please note that i had asked this question a while back but i was unable to attend to it because of some personal issue, so it got deleted, meta user suggested i reask the question and so here it is*

Recently i encountered a website which doesn't send any dynamic information when you try to login, not even `Username` and `Password` !, what i mean is that after i use `Fiddler` and `Http Analyzer` i can see that 4 event happens :
All of these happens in the **web browser** :
[image]
1- A simple `Get` for the login main page
2- A `Post` which sends some data (These data do not include my `Username` and `Password` and they seem static! and even though there is a `__USERCONTROLPATH` which can be extracted from the `step 1` response, it doesn't change, meaning even if i try to login multiple times using different browser at different times everything including the `__USERCONTROLPATH` is the same)
[image]
3- A `Post` which is of `JSON` type and the request is empty and the response only contains a single line as you can see at the image below:
[image]

4- A `Get` happens which is the login main page but if you look at `HTML` you can see that the user is logged in!

I tried doing these steps one by one, but i am unable to successfully log in to the website and i am unable to understand how my `Username` and `Password` is sent!

Here you can see some of the code i have written:

```
//for the sake of cookies and ... i do a Get on the main page 
idHttp.get('MainLogPage');
//i send the first post which contains some information which never changes, they seems static and do not include the username and password 
idhttp.post('someURL', requestList);

jsonRawRequest := TJSONObject.Create;
jsonRequest := TStringStream.Create(jsonRawRequest.ToString, TEncoding.UTF8);
/here i try to do the post that you saw in the image, no value is sent so i send an empty json request.
idhttp.post('someOtherURL', jsonRequest)
```

**In the end my question is** how can i login to such a site ?, what am i missing ?, currently i get error on `Step 3`, when i post the `JSON`, **here is a picture of the error**:
[image]

**Update 01 :**
I meant to update the whole post and explain every step in more detail but as i was messing with fiddler and checking the posts again i noticed something, when the `Browser` sends the `POST` `"https://www.somewebsite.com//Index.aspx/LoginUser"` the type is `application/json` and in the "HTTP analyzer" i can see that it send and receive a `JSON` but in the `Fiddler` the `Webforms` is empty! so i check the `TextView` thats where i saw it !, i again went and check `HTTP` analyzer's Raw stream, and in there i also saw a user and password being sent, i don't know how the post contains this string that you can see below, but in fiddler you can see it in "TextView" and in http analyzer you can see it in raw stream, now that i know this, can you tell me how can i imitate such a post ?, by the way the user and password are encrypted which i presume is a matter of its own, and i probably have to contact the site's admin for the algorithm ?, anyway, first things first, how can i send such a `POST` ?
**In Fiddler :**
[image]

**HTTP Analyzer :**
[image]

**Update 02:**
I tried what `Remy Lebeau` said, 
But the `JSON` in the site was not standard as you can see in:
[The input is not a valid Base-64 string Error, My JSON uses double quotation marks instead of single quotations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53851315/the-input-is-not-a-valid-base-64-string-error-my-json-uses-double-quotation-mar)
After that i tried a hard coded solution and i read the `JSON` from a file as you can see below:

```
loader := TStringList.Create;
loader.LoadFromFile('jsonWithCustomFormat.txt');
jsonRequest := TStringStream.Create(loader[0], TEncoding.UTF8);
```

After that i set the refer to the login page:

```
idHttp.Request.Referer := 'myLoginPageURL';  
idHttp.Request.ContentType := 'application/json'
```

And Finally i send the `POST`:

```
idhttp.Post(URL, jsonRequest, ms);
```

The result of what i did was an alert error as you can in the image below:
[image]

I am very confused as to what the problem is, i have to solve this so any hint or help is much appreciated.